# jQuery Sortable: how to edit containment property behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, customization, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm making a project, it's a simple todo list. You can drag tasks and rearrange it, i have set the tasks `containment` to be the div containing them.

But when you want to put a task at the top, and you simply drag it to the top, the container div stop it from going above the current task at the top.

I want to modify sortable plugin, to add an extra `10px` on the top and the bottom, so the task don't stop exactly at the top of the div, but beyond it with `10px` and the same goes to the bottom of the container div.

Try it yourself to understand what i mean. [here](http://check.staticloud.com/). Add several tasks and try to put some task at the top of the container.

I tried to modify `sortable` using the development bundle, i got to those lines but didn't know what to modify exactly:

```
   if(!(/^(document|window|parent)$/).test(o.containment) && o.containment.constructor != Array) {
       var c = $(o.containment);
       var ce = c[0]; if(!ce) return;
       var co = c.offset();
       var over = ($(ce).css("overflow") != 'hidden');

       this.containment = [
           (parseInt($(ce).css("borderLeftWidth"),10) || 0) + (parseInt($(ce).css("paddingLeft"),10) || 0),
           (parseInt($(ce).css("borderTopWidth"),10) || 0) + (parseInt($(ce).css("paddingTop"),10) || 0),
           (over ? Math.max(ce.scrollWidth,ce.offsetWidth) : ce.offsetWidth) - (parseInt($(ce).css("borderLeftWidth"),10) || 0) - (parseInt($(ce).css("paddingRight"),10) || 0) - this.helperProportions.width - this.margins.left - this.margins.right,
           (over ? Math.max(ce.scrollHeight,ce.offsetHeight) : ce.offsetHeight) - (parseInt($(ce).css("borderTopWidth"),10) || 0) - (parseInt($(ce).css("paddingBottom"),10) || 0) - this.helperProportions.height - this.margins.top  - this.margins.bottom
       ];
    this.relative_container = c;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, It seems that i have solved it, to anyone having this issue add this option to the `sortable` :

```
tolerance: "pointer"
```

> This is the way the reordering behaves during drag. Possible values:
>   'intersect', 'pointer'. In some setups, 'pointer' is more natural.
>
> - **intersect**: draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50%
> - **pointer**: mouse pointer overlaps the droppable

Strangely, `intersect` is the default value, where it could be much better to make `pointer` is the default one.